# Service endpoints cannot be found via UDP multicast

Tags: wcf, service-discovery, adhoc

I have a self-hosted WCF service and a client which uses UDP multicast discovery to find service endpoints. I have tested them on a local machine, so both discovery and web method calls worked correctly. Once I tried to run on a LAN, discovery no longer finds any endpoints.

Both machines ping from each other, moreover with explicitly specified endpoint - the client successfully invokes service methods. I came across some discussions on message level security and I took some measures to disable it like:

`[ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]`

```
<security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
```

and

```
new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpBindingSecurityMode.None)
```

Now I ran out of ideas and google doesn't yield any fruitful results. And most of the code samples are just saying how easy this is and completely ignore the security aspect.

Please, any suggestions on why cross machine discovery does not work?

Comment: I know this is old, but have your turned off your firewall to rule it out?